# How do I skip(1) (the header line) with a where bool statement linq

Tags: linq

Sorry if this is a newbie question. I'm new to Linq
I'm trying to figure out how to use a where statement to ignore the first line on a csv import. I can do it using Skip(1) but I'm not sure how to write it in a where statement.

here is how im doing it with a skip(1)

```
List<string> allLinesText = File.ReadAllLines(filename).
Skip(1).
Take(100).
ToList();
```

If I change Skip(1) to where(line => ...
How could I write it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish doing that? Not sure what to recommend.

Comment: Do you want to skip the first line only if a certain condition is true?

Comment: Yes Steve, I'm trying to write as a true or false. Since line 0 is the headers I'd like to ignore it.

Comment: So this boils down on how to identify if the first line is an header or not

Comment: Yes, Sorry if I was vague, I'm still pretty new to this.

Comment: Are you trying to always skip the first line or have a bool that will allow you to optionally skip the first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Where is a must, Where() has an index option.

```
.Where( (row, index) => index > 0 )
```

For a conditional skip like a header you could phrase it with Skip :

```
.Skip( hasHeader ? 1 : 0 )
```

Or insisting on Where:

```
.Where( (row, index) => !hasHeader || index > 0 )
```

And actually, doing Linq with CSV, I suggest you to look into Linq To CSV on codeplex.

PS: A CSV processing by Linq might not be as easy as it sounds. Depends on your version of CSV file. For example this file is not a legal CSV by some and it is by the other (ie: PostgreSQL would successfully import this as a CSV but not Excel, nor SQL server):

```
1, "Yellow
Red
Blue", "Still On the first row"
```

Comment: He says, he is looking for a Where that accomplishes Skip(1).

Comment: @CetinBasoz follow the comments where he clarified its intentions

Comment: Isn't it funny that SO users downvote for you answer the exact question or they like to downvote when you try to show the right way to a user :) Go figure how you can satisfy all.

Comment: @Steve, I wouldn't sit in front of the computer, waiting a question or comments be edited all day long.

Answer (score 3):

Although @Cetin's reply is exactly what you were asking, based on your comments above, what I believe you're looking to accomplish could be done using an inline if statement checking if there is a need to skip the first line or not as follows:

```
bool isFirstLineHeader;
// Set the isFirstLineHeader variable here (or passed in through an argument)

List<string> allLinesText = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
.Skip(isFirstLineHeader ? 1 : 0)
.Take(100)
.ToList();
```

Hope this helps.